# How to stop a function within click event

Tags: jquery

I have validate function to handle value:

```
function validateForm() {
    $(".contact-form-email").each(function() {
        var title1 = this.value;
        if (!isEmail(title1)) {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').hide();
        }
    });
    $(".eachrequire").each(function() {
        var title = this.value;
        if (title == "" || title == null) {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I added this function into click event.

```
  $('.checkall').click(function(){
                  validateForm(1, false);
                  $('.sendForm').click();
  });
```

How can stop `$('.sendForm').click()` if `validateForm` above is not passed.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make validate function return true/false value based on pass or fail respectively and then based on it trigger click.

```
 $('.checkall').click(function(){
     var isValid = validateForm();
     if(isValid)
       $('.sendForm').click();
  });
```

Your validate function

```
function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
    $(".contact-form-email").each(function() {

        var title1 = this.value;
        if (!isEmail(title1)) {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').show();
            isValid = false;
            return false; // breakout of each function
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').hide();
        }
    });

    //Check for next validation
    if(isValid)
    {
      $(".eachrequire").each(function() {
         var title = this.value;
         if (title == "" || title == null) {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').show();
            isValid=false;
            return false; // breakout of each looping function
         } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-section').find('.message-show').hide();
         }
      });
    }
  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Must I repair validateForm ? If yes, how I can repair it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use event.stopPropagation() within the click event

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/